# Qual o melhor repositório para o Maven?

Tags: java, maven, repository

As vezes não consigo encontrar as dependências em um repositório, então onde devo procurar essas dependências? Existe algum núcleo onde todas as possíveis dependências estarão por lá?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## TD;DR

Não existe "melhor repositório".

## Descubra o repositório oficial

Cada projeto fica hospedado em um repositório. No máximo ele pode ser espelhado em outros repositórios.

Por exemplo, os projetos JBoss possuem um repositório próprio onde você encontra todos os produtos em suas últimas versões, mas após algum tempo o repositório é sincronizado com o Central do maven. Então é recomendável adicionar o repositório do JBoss ao seu projeto se quiser ter as últimas atualizações.

Para saber o repositório oficial de uma biblioteca, você deve olhar sempre na documentação ou no site oficial.

## Repositórios privados

É importante lembrar que cada empresa geralmente tem seu repositório privado/interno para armazenar os artefatos de seus produtos em desenvolvimento.

Portanto, é sempre bom manter o seu arquivo `settings.xml` atualizado com os padrões da empresa. Confira com os responsáveis sobre o padrão. Além disso, configure os respectivos repositórios adicionais em cada projeto que necessite de artefatos que não estão no Central.

## Determinando e pesquisando as dependências

Se tiver dúvidas sobre alguma dependência, você pode pesquisar em sites como o [MVN Repository](http://mvnrepository.com/), que nada mais é do que um indexador do Maven Central.

Infelizmente, algumas vezes encontrar uma dependência específica não basta. Muitos projetos necessitam de um conjunto dependências que não é nada intuitivo de descobrir. Isso é comum em projetos JEE.

Nesses casos, o melhor é procurar um exemplo de projeto ao invés de tentar adivinhar todas as dependências necessárias para trabalhar com uma tecnologia, afinal isso pode variar de acordo com o tipo de projeto.

Por exemplo, dependendo do Servidor de Aplicação usado numa aplicação web, você pode ter que configurar seu pom de forma diferente, pois esses servidores disponibilizam diferentes bibliotecas.

Comment: Obrigado. Já observei  alguns projetos simples estou analisando  um exemplo que  usa maven  aplicação web . Fiquei na duvida porque existiam umas dependências difíceis de encontrar.